# Showing the function $f(x,y)$ is one by one

Tags: geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus, hyperbolic-geometry

Yesterday, while teaching geometry, I was faced to a problem saying that the function below is an distance function: $$d(P,Q)=\Big|\ln\frac{\frac{x_1-c+r}{y_1}}{\frac{x_2-c+r}{y_2}}\Big|$$ where in $P|_{y_1}^{x_1}$, $Q|_{y_2}^{x_2}$ are points in $\mathbb R^2$ and $y_i>0$. In fact, I am working on [Poincaré half-plane model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) to show that the above function has the following properties:

$*_1$ $d(P,Q)\geq 0$

$*_2$ $d(P,Q)=d(Q,P)$ for every points in above plane.

$*_3$ $d(P,Q)=0\Longleftrightarrow P=Q$.

And we don't have the triangle inequality condition here. Honestly, I chose this problem and thought it was easy to the end. Every things went OK, but while probing the second condition $(\Longrightarrow)$; I found out that I should show the function $$f(x,y)=|\ln\frac{x-c+r}{y}|$$ where $c,r$ are positive reals and $(x-c)^2+y^2=r^2$ is one by one. I could not make my guess proved in the class. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean one-to-one, injective?

Comment: Also, should we assume $y>0$ and either $x-c \ge 0$ or no modulus? The first seems obvious. For the latter, note that $\log((x-c+r)/\sqrt{r^2-(x-c)^2} = (x-c)/r + \mathcal{O}((x-c)^2)$ so that the absolute value is not one-to-one, because it is linear in $x-c$.

Comment: Dedicated teacher! +1

Comment: Since we already have tags for [tag:hyperbolic-geometry] and [tag:spherical-geometry], I encourage their use instead of (noneuclidean-...); for geometries that are neither Euclidean, hyperbolic, nor spherical, one should just use [tag:riemannian-geometry], [tag:differential-geometry], or [tag:metric-geometry] as appropriate.

Comment: @WillieWong: Ok. I didn't know that. I'll do that certainly. :)

Comment: @BabakS.: Hi.I may not say it always.
But, I mean it whenever I say it.
Thank You Teacher.
For all the things you have done for me.
*Happy Teachers Day!*

Comment: @flashdesign2550: Your Welcome!

Comment: @BabakS.:
You are not only our teacher.
Rather, you are philosopher and guide, all molded into one person.
*We will always be grateful to you for your support*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $(x-c)^2+y^2=r^2$ we may write $x=c+r\cos t,\ y= r \sin t.$ From $y>0$ we also have $0<t<\pi$ here. Then
$$\frac{x-c+r}{y}=\frac{\cos t+1}{\sin t},$$
and the latter is strictly monotone decreasing on $(0,\pi)$.

The function $\ln$ being one to one, this shows $f(x,y)$ is also one-to-one. [note maybe the absolute values should be taken before the $\ln$ (to make input to $\ln$ positive).

Answer (score 2):

Let $$u = x-c, y = \sqrt{r^2 - u^2}$$

Then
$$\tilde{f}(x,y) = \log \frac{x-c+r}{y} = \log \frac{u+r}{\sqrt{r^2 - u^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{r+u}{r-u} $$

Now note that the denominator decreases from $2r$ to $0$ as $u$ increases from $-r$ to $r$, and the numerator increases from $0$ to $2r$. Thus the function is monotonic for the relevant range $-r < x-c < r$, and therefore one-to-one.

---

Now note that $y>0$ holds for you; and that for the condition you were trying to prove you want $\tilde{f}$, not $f = \left| \tilde{f} \right|$, to be monotonic, since
$$\left| \log\frac{\cdots}{\cdots}\right| = \left| \tilde{f}(\cdots) - \tilde{f}(\cdots)\right| = 0$$ is the condition of interest.

Comment: Thanks so much for what you have done for me. Thanks Sharkos. :-)